# Read Free Space in external SD card in android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

i write methods but it return only internal memory space. But i want SD card memory free space size.

```
  public static String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
            if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
                File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
                long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
                long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
                return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
            } else {
                return "Exception";
            }
        }
```

// here return in MB

```
 public static String formatSize(long size) {
        String suffix = null;

        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "KB";
            size /= 1024;
            if (size >= 1024) {
                suffix = "MB";
                size /= 1024;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

        int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
        while (commaOffset > 0) {
            resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
            commaOffset -= 3;
        }

        if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
        return resultBuffer.toString();
    }
```

// Check is external Memory is there.

```
 public static boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
                return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
            }
```

Comment: `it return only internal memory space`. No. External storage space. Look at the function name of the function you use. That gives external storage path. Which is different from sd card path indeed.